# Is there a filter for Checkout Error Message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I would like to edit the text on the checkout page. `There are some issues with the items in your cart. Please go back to the cart page and resolve these issues before checking out.`

I've been searching for ways to edit it without editing the source file. Is there a filter to edit the text on checkout page?

tried this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'quadlayers', 9999, 2);
function quadlayers( $fields, $errors ){
// in case any validation errors
if( !empty( $errors->get_error_codes() ) ) {

// omit all existing error messages
foreach( $errors->get_error_codes() as $code ) {
$errors->remove( $code );
}
// display custom single error message
$errors->add( 'validation', 'Your Custom Message Goes Here!!!' );
}
}
```

Comment: _"Is there a filter to edit the text at check out page, without editing the source file?"_ Yes, by using the [gettext()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/) filter hook but this filter is ideally avoided as the performance aspect can be huge, this can easily run thousands of times on one page. Another option is by modifying the translation files in WooCommerce

Comment: You can modify the WooCommerce template by adding the custom file in your child theme. The original file is located in: `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/cart-errors.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter('gettext_woocommerce', 'modify_cart_error_message', 10, 3);

function modify_cart_error_message($translation, $text, $domain) {
    if ('There are some issues with the items in your cart. Please go back to the cart page and resolve these issues before checking out.' === $translation) {
        $translation = 'Your Custom Message Goes Here!!!';
    }
    return $translation;
}
```

The cart error message mentioned is coming from `/woocommerce/templates/checkout/cart-errors.php` file. Either you can *override the template in themes* or use the above code snippet in the active theme `functions.php` file